# FLEX: What is the regex for matching both positive-negative integer and floating point number where exponent can be present also?

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I want to match number like---

**10** **, -10,** **10E5** **,10e5**

as an integer number and number like--

**10.554**  **,-10.5** **,10.5E5** **,-10.5e-5**

as a floating pointer number.

How can I achieve it in lexical analyzer FLEX?

I am trying in this way:

```
^[+-]?\d+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$ {++CountInteger;}
^[-+]?[0-9]*[.][0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$ {++CountFloat;}
```

but it is not working ,what is the problem in my case and what should be the solution for it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove ^ and $ unless you want to match lines which contain nothing other than a single number. When you have a problem with a regular expression, build it up by in small steps and make sure it works as you expect after each step.

Comment: ...which contain nothing other than a single number.. might better hammer the point home.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have proven that you are working with a number and all you need is to see if it is an integer or a floating point number, your regex could be super simple by just checking for the existence of a `.`.

e.g. the pattern would be `"\."`. If that works for you - awesome! Easier is often better!

If you need to prove that you have a number, then things get a little more complicated. I'd suggest:

For integers - `^-?\d+([eE]-?\d+)?$`

- Optional negative sign `-?`, one or more digits `\d+`, then the optional exponent piece `([eE]-?\d+)?`.
- - Exponent piece should have either 'e' or 'E' `[eE]`, an optional negative sign `-?`, and one or more digits for the exponent `\d+`

For floating point numbers - it is only slightly modified: `^-?\d+\.\d+([eE]-?\d+)?$`

- The modification is the `\.\d+` bit which will exactly match the `.` and one or more digits following the period.

Answer (score 0):

A little visualizion:

[image: path of -?\d+([eE]-?\d+)?]

(created at [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=-%3F%5Cd%2B(%5BeE%5D-%3F%5Cd%2B)%3F))

See also:

- [Debuggex](https://debuggex.com)
- [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)